# How to access member variables of class from function

Tags: node.js

I have two classes

### Class 1-

```
var dict = {};
class EventManager {
  constructor() {}

  subscribeForEvents(subscriber) {
    var emitter = null;
    if (dict.hasOwnProperty(subscriber.url)) {
      emitter = dict[subscriber.url];
    } else {
      emitter = new EventEmitter();
      dict[subscriber.url] = emitter;
    }
    emitter.on(subscriber.url, subscriber.onMessage);
    console.log("Number of listerner", emitter.listenerCount());
  }

  sendMessage(url,msg ){
    var emitter = dict[url];
    emitter.emit(url, msg);
  }
}
```

### Class 2

```
class Subscriber {
  constructor(url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.onMessage = function(data) {
      console.log(this);
      console.log(this.url);
    };
}
}
```

Here is how i am using both class in a third file of nodejs

```
const EventManager = require("./eventManager");
const eventManager = new EventManager();
const Subscriber = require("./eventSubscriber");
const eventSubscriber = new Subscriber("some_url");
eventManager.subscribeForEvents(eventSubscriber);

eventManager.sendMessage("some_url", {some : data});
```

Now on running above code when **sendMessage** triggers **emit** function, **onMessage** gets invoked but **console.log(this)** gives me

```
EventEmitter {
  domain: null,
  _events: { 'incoming_call_updates/0712fa33-63ba-11e6-b56f-066beb27a027/konnect': [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined }
```

which is a not a instance of **Subscriber** class and so **this.url** gives me **undefined**.

How can i access **subscriber** object/variables that was set at
*emitter.on(subscriber.url, **subscriber**.onMessage);*.

Comment: `this` is the function, when you're inside the function.  Just use `url`.

Comment: Try `constructor(url) { this.url = url; var me = this; this.onMessage = function(data) { console.log(me); } }` or use arrow function: `constructor(url) { this.url = url; this.onMessage = (data) => { console.log(this); } }`